# Punisher spin off in defender series

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Marvel's *Defenders* cross-over series will be airing after *Iron Fist*, featuring Daredevil, Luke Cage, Iron Fist, and Jessica Jones. In *Daredevil* season 2, the Punisher character's fate was also left open-ended. Will he be getting his own series?

Comment: __[The Punisher (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Punisher_(TV_series))__

Comment: I suspect your question about if Punisher was "worthy" of his own series was attracting close votes -- that's personal opinion. I have edit the question to focus on the objectively answerable part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Punisher netflix series slated for release this year. It was ordered in April 2016 and began filming in October.